# VBscript to close current IE tab

Tags: vbscript

Just spent two day to find a simple solution to an even more simple problem.. feeling kinda stupid..
I have an asp web page which opens in a new tab (once navigated to) and consist of a VBscript which redirect to a certin exe file.
all I want is to automatically close that tab once the exe was executed.

here is the vbscript:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
set oWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oWshShell.run "\\SomeServer\Remote\someEXE.exe <%=Request("Name")%> \\SomeServer",1,False
</script>
```

Thanks,
Liron

Comment: Try `window.close()` or `self.close()`. Only the child window created with `window.open()` can be closed without prompt.

Answer (score 0):

As @omegastripes said `window.close()` promped me to close the window, but when I've added `window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();` as a java script outside my vbscript, the windows closed without a prompt